# Suitable acid/base combo

Tags: home-experiment

I've been trying to get any chemical reaction that with the least *volume* of reagents (including possible water) would generate the highest amount of a safe gas (at a reasonable cost and with a fast reaction).

The final implementation would be having small, portable and stable reagents (preferably solid) that could be mixed at any moment to fill up a balloon. To be used by the general public without much reagent handling (e.g. irritants would be ok).

Currently by best guess has been citric acid with any of the 1st group (bi)carbonates, adding water before to each, and then mixing them.

Does anyone have another suitable reaction?
Any other safe acid?
Any more soluble option to reduce the water volume?

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site and visit the [help] if questions about it remain. I’m not sure about your question, as it stands it is rather broad. It may get closed for being too broad. If you can narrow it down more, you should. E.g. are you restricted in which safe gas is generated?

Comment: dry ice would be about as good as you could do relative volume wise. "safe" is relative. I wouldn't hold the dry ice in my hand.

Comment: thanks for the tips already and the welcome. edited further for clarity